# How do you fix the escape characters in TCL for Sublime Text 2?

Tags: tcl, highlight, sublimetext2

It seems the following two lines of code are breaking the syntax coloring in TCL.

```
regsub -all {/} $original {\\\\} target      # The last } is being escaped

set grep_keyword [string trim $grep_keyword {"}]   # The " character is starting a new quote
```

This code was like this when I opened the files.  Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Are you wanting to fix the code, or fix Sublime Text 2?

Comment: I suppose I could fix the code, but there's always the risk of breaking something.  These scripts are part of a "mission critical" system that is really bad if it breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I came back to this and put some effort into solving my problem.  I altered the tmLangauge file for TCL.  The } character is recognized as the ending brace.  I just added \} to this definition as well.

```
<key>braces</key>
<dict>
    <key>begin</key>
    <string>(?:^|(?&lt;=\s))\{</string>
    <key>comment</key>
    <string>matches a single brace-enclosed word</string>
    <key>end</key>
    <string>\}([^\s\]]*)</string>
    <key>endCaptures</key>
    <dict>
        <key>1</key>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>invalid.illegal.tcl</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>patterns</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>match</key>
            <string>\\[{}\n]</string>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>constant.character.escape.tcl</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>include</key>
            <string>#inner-braces</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

In the above, I made a modification to the RegEx to look like so:

```
<string>\}([^\s\]]*)|\\}\s</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

While the problem is technically with Sublime Text 2 (Tcl isn't very simple to highlight correctly in some corner cases, which you've found) it's easier to alter the Tcl code to something semantically-equivalent.

```
regsub -all {/} $original "\\\\\\\\" target
```

```
set grep_keyword [string trim $grep_keyword "\""]
```

You might consider using `string map` for the first one, of course:

```
set target [string map {"/" "\\\\"} $original]
# or this:
#    set target [string map {/ {\\}} $original]
# but I'm not sure if the editor will like that...
```

Comment: Thank you, much, for your suggestion.  This is probably what I'm going to end up doing.